# EC2 port 80: Connection refused

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm doing a GET request to my EC2 instance, but I'm getting the following error:

```
80: Connection refused
```

These are the security rules of my instance:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source           launch-wizard-1
80         tcp     0.0.0.0/0            ✔
22         tcp     177.32.53.207/32     ✔
```

What's wrong with these rules? Why can't I access port 80?

EDIT
[I attached my apache conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)](http://www.filedropper.com/apache2) in this url, since it's too big to post all the code here.

EDIT2
when I run netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
I get this:

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Do you have software on the instance that serves a response on port 80 (e.g. a web server)? Is it running? Do you see anything in your error logs?

Comment: In addition to what Robbie said, make sure that whatever application running on the server listening to port 80 is bound the correct interface / IP.  If it's only listening to localhost or to the non-public IP address, it won't respond on the public IP address.

Comment: @RobbieAverill yes I have apache. But I checked the logs on var/log/apache2/error.log and I see nothing related to the port.

Comment: @Brooks how can I do this with apache?

Comment: Which version of Apache?  Check the conf file or maybe paste your conf file into your question.  Also make sure apache is actually running (in linux, run 'sudo service apache2 status' - assuming apache2).

Comment: @Brooks I attached the apache conf file in my question. I'm using Apache 2.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't in there, sorry.  How about your /sites-available/000-default file?  I don't really work much with Apache, but this url might help.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html  Also, try SSH into the instance and curl from there (i.e. curl -XGET 'http://localhost:80' or curl -XGET 'http://<<local_IP>>:80').  Make sure apache is in fact running.

Comment: Yes, "connection refused" could be two things: 1) There is no process listening on port 80. 2) There is a process listening, but it's bound to 127.0.0.1. It should be bound to 0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: @Brooks I don't think it's on 000-default file the problem, there is no ip settings there. When I try curl -XGET 'localhost:80' works fine.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency where can I find these settings? I'm using a Ubuntu 14 machine and apache2 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the source of your connection request?  Are you attempting to access your instance from outside of Amazon or from a difference EC2 instance in the same availability zone?  Are you supplying an IP address or a DNS name as the argument to your connecting code?

Keep in mind that AWS EC2 uses SDN (software defined networking) which doesn't work quite like classical TCP/IP routing that you may be expecting from using Linux, or other OSes, on bare metal systems (or even on VMs using more traditional networking).

Ultimately you will probably want to allocate "elastic IP" (EIP) from AWS and bind it to your web server instance.  Then route your requests to that IP address.  (Often you'd also create a DNS entry, perhaps through Amazon's "Route53" service to use the a name rather than the address).

It's possible to get to your instance from within and from outside their network. But you have to use the Amazon generated DNS name to do so then, because they use split-horizon, your clients will get the correct (internal or external) IP address.

Also you have to consider the security settings on your VPC (virtual private cloud) network(s) as well as those you've applied to your instance.